# In Python, given a text file with some data and URL, what is the simplest way to read only the url of the text file?

Tags: python-2.7

In python I want to read the url in a text file like this, but with more than 1000 lines. How can i take only the url of every line? I need to download the photos to my dataset. 
Thanks

=============

> Lexi Ainsworth    1   1
>   http://cdn.soaps.sheknows.com/images/news/22537_1_15562.jpg   45,50,174,179   571435cb57e518ae0cc5855eb8f1bea0b89d447d8ad7f9379fbfb3ab794333f5
>   Lexi Ainsworth    2   2
>   http://trialx.com/curetalk/wp-content/blogs.dir/7/files/2011/10/celebrities/Lexi_Ainsworth-1.jpg  130,112,396,378

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Ok, i got it, thank u for ur help anyways, I put the code here, maybe for someone can be helpful. Create a txt with only the url's

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re

# read the original text
 f=file("yourtextfile.txt", "r")
 content=f.read().splitlines()
 f.close()

# create the new file to save the url's
 f = file("newfile.txt","w")
 f = open("newfile.txt","w")
# for every line in the text
 for line in content:
    a = line
    contador = 0
    contador2 = 1
    for charac in a:
        # for every character in the line
        if charac == "\t" :
            # if the next characters after \t are http we copy the url till other \t appear
            if a[contador2:contador2+4] == 'http':
                url = ""
                while a[contador2] != "\t":
                    url = url + a[contador2]
                    contador2 = contador2+1

                f.write(url + '\n')
         contador = contador +1
         contador2 = contador2 +1
 f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You do have a hard problem, because the URL can be e.g. enclosed in parentheses. How do you know if the closing parenthesis is part of the URL or not part of the URL?

This sounds like a job for regular expressions, but unfortunately it isn't pretty and it isn't perfect. See http://www.regexguru.com/2008/11/detecting-urls-in-a-block-of-text/ for some examples and comments on why the problem is hard.

See this example for something that sort of works:

```
re.match('.*(https?://[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%=~_|])', 'abc http://www.google.fi def').groups(0)
```

Comment: The document are lines where each of them is the name first, then the id, then the id of the face, then the url and finally separated coordinates between spaces. I searched parentheses and throughout the document there is none, so the parenthesis are no a problem. But I still do not know how, I will look at the page that told me to see if I can find the way.Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Split the whole string with respect to spaces, and select all sub-strings that start with http/https? I am assuming that you are restricted to these 2 protocols for all intents and purposes.

The problem arises when you do not know if the line ended with a complete hyperlink or if the hyperlink continues in the next line.

Comment: How can I work with sub-string in python? There are 2 single lines in the example
Can I read like this?
======
import re

f=file("xt.txt", "r")
content=f.read().splitlines()
f.close()

f=file("newfile.txt","w")

# read all lines
for line in content:
        f.write(line+"\n")
f = open("newfile.txt","r")
lineas = f.readlines()